# Can I use Defender Aura without ending Berserker Fury?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I created a Minotaur Barbarian (Berserker) Level 1 with the Character Builder. I got the Berserker Fury feat and it reads:

> Enter Berserker fury until end of encounter when you use a barbarian primal attack power or as a minor action when bloodied: defender's aura ends, melee basic attacks deal 1D8 extra damage

If I understand correctly my *Devastating Strike*, *Howling Strike*, *Avalanche Strike* and *Swift Panther Rage* make me enter the fury. But I was wondering about the *Defender Aura*, can I use it after getting into the Fury?

If you need to see the [character sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzqjyzx589wvkzm/torito%20lvl1.pdf)

Comment: All your powers end your Defender Aura. All your powers are better on an original Barbarian. Why do not you just play a Barbarian?

Comment: I´m new to character creation and I was helping someone building this berserker. I guess I'll redo the powers.

Comment: Berserker is not for beginners. It is not for anyone really. ;) If you want a defender, create a Knight, if a striker, play a Barbarian. Those are really beginner friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

Once you enter *Berserker Fury* your *Defender Aura* disappears and you cannot reactivate it (minor action) until you are no longer in Berserker Fury.

> BERSERKER FURY
>
> When you use a barbarian primal attack power, you enter your Berserker Fury until the end of the encounter. Alternatively, you can use a minor action while you are bloodied to enter the fury. The fury has the following effects.
>
> - Your defender aura ends, if it was active, and you cannot use defender aura or vengeful guardian until the fury ends.
> - Some of your powers, such as your barbarian martial at-will attack powers, gain additional benefits, as noted in those powers.
> - Your melee basic attacks deal 1d8 extra damage. This extra damage increases to 2d8 at 11th level and 3d8 at 21st level.

Published in Heroes of the Feywild, page(s) 42.

Comment: There tossed the reference page at the end of my answer.